# Can I Use My Brokerage's API With Javascript Instead Of C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm a customer of Questrade (online trading brokerage) and want to utilize their new API to experiment with automated trades. Essentially I would create a simple app that monitors prices of specific stocks and executes a pre-programmed strategy when I'm not around.

The company offers sample applications in C++ and C# to aid developers. I'm not really a developer though and I've never used C#. Their C# sample app doesn't even run on my computer for some reason (Windows 10, Visual Studio). But I do have Javascript experience.

Several years ago when I was really exercising those skills, creating a windows app out of Javascript was about as simple as using a .HTA extension. I see now that it's still possible although I need to look farther into how it's done in Windows 10.

Anyway my question is can a Javascript app utilize the proper API commands? There's a list at this link: http://www.questrade.com/api/documentation/getting-started

If the answer is no then I'll just continue learning C#, it'll just take longer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A brief look shows the API is entirely in JSON, so yes, you can use practically any language. Make an HTTP request to the API and get back JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use any language of your choice to use this API.

If you want to go with javascript you'll have to make ajax calls to their API. You can use JQuery for this as it can handle the ajax calls and the Json response parsing.